# c++ program to open terminal and display output in that new terminal

Tags: c++, terminal

I want to write a c++ program to open new terminal and program  should display all further "cout <<" statements in New terminal.Please help...Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ program, when successfully built, should open in a new terminal window (or command prompt on Windows computers), and all "cout" statements will display in that window.

**Note: Applies to Windows only.**
If you want to start another new window, you can make another program then run it by using system("start [insert file name here, with full path]");. #include  is necessary for program starting to work. The window that you want to open also has to be created from a C++ source file.

Source: 1 month of experience C++ experience (using CodeBlocks)

If there's another way (or easier way), make a comment or make a new answer.

Comment: I think shell (or command prompt or codeblock) is opening the new window, then launching  program A in it.  I interpreted the question to be after manually launching C++ program A, how can A create a terminal then launch B in it.  I think there might be an exec for that.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.04, g++ 4.9.2,

- create a cpp program, call it pgmA. (file pgmA.cc)
- pgmA (executable) would use "popen" to spawn a second process, a terminal, and for ubuntu I would use  "gnome-terminal "
- Append to the gnome-terminal command the option " --command=./pgmB", (from pgmB.cc)

Result: pgmB runs in the new terminal, with all pgmB output going to that terminal.

Comment: FYI - all std::cout of pgmA goes to the original terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    // Open a new terminal window
    system("gnome-terminal");

    // Display output in the new terminal window
    system("echo 'Hello, world!' > /dev/pts/1");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout` statements won't be printed in the new terminal.